# Auto Increment version code in IntelliJ IDEA (Android)

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea

How can I have auto increment `versionCode` (or `versionName`) in IntelliJ IDEA for an Android project?

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758685/auto-increment-version-code-in-android-app) another SO question already asked for Eclipse.